# Check on checkbox, reset an input

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, input

## I have

an input and a checkbox.

[image]

---

## My goal

is when the user change something on the input box, I want to start showing the `set to default` checkbox.

Then, when the `set to default` checkbox is `check`, I want to set back the original value into that input.

---

Here is what I have tried

## HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <input id="onboard_url" value="{{ $g_portal_url or ''}}" class="form-control" name="onboard_url" required placeholder="Ex. https://www.onboading.com" >
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2" style="display: none;" id="onboard_url_default">
    <input type="checkbox" id="onboard_url_default_cb" value="0" >
    Set to default
</div>
```

---

## jQuery

```
$('#onboard_url').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#onboard_url_default').show();

    if($('#onboard_url_default_cb').prop('checked')){
        $('#onboard_url_default_cb').val(1);
        console.log('checked');
        $("#onboard_url").val('');
        $("#onboard_url").val('{{ $g_portal_url or ''}}');
    }
});
```

---

```
$('#onboard_url').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#onboard_url_default').show();

    if($('#onboard_url_default_cb').is(':checked')){
        $('#onboard_url_default_cb').val(1);
        console.log('checked');
        $("#onboard_url").val('');
        $("#onboard_url").val('{{ $g_portal_url or ''}}');
    }
});
```

---

## Result

I couldn't get my `console.log` to print.

I'm not sure what I missed here. :(

Comment: You haven't bound any code to the checkbox's change or click event

Comment: prop('checked') ? I thought I check it here to see if it is checked.

Comment: In the code you have, you are checking if the checkbox is checked only when typing in the text field. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: @ihue It sounds as though your logic is flawed, however you should change your `if` statement to `.is(':checked')`.

Comment: Okay. Let me try that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, using checkbox for this situation is wrong for UX. The best way is using a button for it. Here is my code is for button;

```
$(function(){
    $('#your_button').click(function(){
        $("#onboard_url").val('');
        $("#onboard_url").val('{{ $g_portal_url or ''}}');
    });
});
```

For checkbox, this is the solution;

```
$(function(){
    $('#onboard_url').on('keyup', function() {
        $('#onboard_url_default').show();
    });

    $('#onboard_url_default_cb').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $(this).val(1);
            $("#onboard_url").val('');
            $("#onboard_url").val("{{ $g_portal_url or ''}}");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's present in the original code, but you may want to change the `val('{{ $g_portal_url or ''}}')` to `val("{{ $g_portal_url or ''}}")` (or escape those single quotes so you're not trying to set the value to two separate strings)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion !

Comment: I agree with @taha_emin in the sense that using a checkbox is wrong from UX point of view. Imagine the situation when the user checks it, and then decided to not go with the **default** one and now changes the URL. So now you'll be in trouble as now the user is typing his/her own URL, but your check box is already checked. So, using a button is a better approach.